# The logrotate 'rotate' directive and migrating from daily to weekly

Tags: logrotate, log-rotation

I have a server collecting syslog messages from the network.  Logrotate is currently setup and working, and the config looks like such:

```
/logs/*/log {
    daily
    rotate 60
}
```

Instead of rotating daily, I'd like weekly.  Obviously, I'm keeping 60 days' logs, so I would likely be changing the `rotate 60` to `rotate 8`, which would keep 8 weeks' logs.

My questions are these:

1. If I change from daily to weekly and keep 8 logs, when logrotate
   runs will it delete the 52 oldest daily logs, or is it smart enough
   to notice the date stamps on the files, and realize that 8 weeks’
   time is 2 months ago?
2. If I run logrotate manually with the `-f` flag
   to force rotation, and I did this 8 times, would I effectively wipe
   all logs completely?
3. If I go into the `logrotate.status` file and
   manually remove one particular log, what will happen to that
   particular log when logrotate runs next?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you change the number of logs, then at the next run logrotate will ensure that at most that many logs are kept. The number is not necessarily related to number of days (you could run logrotate hourly if you configure it correctly).
2. Yes, unless you have the `notifempty` setting (which I do recommend).
3. Same as if you re-added that log to the configuration after having removed it. It will rotate the log as it doesn't know when that might have been done previously, and it will preserve the required number of logs as per point 1.